# Is CentOS using synchronous or asynchronous write

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk

Is CentOS using synchronous or asynchronous write? Is ther any way to check or to change this?

Answer (score 4):

By default, all writes are asynchronous.

You can configure them to be synchronous at the application level `O_DIRECT|O_SYNC` `open(2)` flags, or at the file system one (`-o sync` option of the mount command).

Answer (score 2):

According to Red Hat's (rather old) page *[12.5. Verifying Asynchronous I/O Usage](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/sect-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Enabling_Asynchronous_IO_and_Direct_IO_Support-Verifying_Asynchronous_IO_Usage.html)*, asynchronous I/O is supported using libaio.  Applications either are, or are not linked with that library.  There is nothing mentioned about enabling or disabling: applications simply *use* the library.  The page says you can verify usage by inspecting `/proc/slabinfo`.

In my CentOS 6 machine, with 2466 files in `/usr/bin`, only 3 are linked with libaio:

- btreplay
- qemu-img
- qemu-io

There are programs which use this feature, but not many.  Some people confuse this with the buffer cache.

Further reading:

- [Kernel Asynchronous I/O (AIO) Support for Linux](http://lse.sourceforge.net/io/aio.html)
- [Direct and Asynchronous I/O](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/direct-and-asynchronous-io)

> I/O operations in UNIX and Linux systems typically go through the file system cache. Although this doesn't represent a problem in itself, this extra processing does require resources. Bypassing the file system cache reduces CPU requirements, and frees up the file system cache for other non-database file operations. Operations against raw devices automatically bypass the file system cache.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the fact that in Linux, writes are not all immediately flushed to the underlying device but set as _dirty pages_ which are flushed to disk (using pdflush) via the IO scheduler, which itself may introduce another delay (unless noop scheduler is used). I am not sure what the default page-flushing values are with CentOS 6, but there could be a 30 second delay. See http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch15lev1sec4

Answer (score 0):

As /u/jiliagre [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278297/105631), you cat force `O_SYNC` with the file-open or at mount-time via `-o sync` flag, per device (you can remount most open mountpoints with `mount -o remount,sync <mtpt>`. Alternatively, you can tell the system to immediately schedule a flush every time it does a write (which "dirties a page").

When sync mode is not enabled, the complicated writeback algorithms come into play. The writeback algorithm is designed to *limit* IO operations. It assumes that the user prefers the system perform flushes to disk only occasionally: either after a deadline or when there are a threshold of "dirty" pages to flush. To do the flushing, it simply assigns some work to and "wakes up" the kernel thread(s) `pdflush`.

There are a few system variables you can manipulate via `sysctl` and `/proc/` to control writeback's behavior. You are primarily interested in:

```
vm.dirty_background_ratio     = 0
```

which essentially forces every dirty write to wake up and be flushed; and/or

```
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs  = 1
```

which ensures dirty pages are flushed every 1/100th of a second. You might be tempted to set the latter to 0, but that will actually disable the timer. You might also be tempted to set `vm.dirty_ratio` to 0, but at least in 2.6.25, this is lower-capped at 5% and will not help you here.

Caveat #1: The writeback algorithm employs rate-limiting behavior. I'm not completely sure of the algorithm, as it's complicated, but if so many pages are to be flushed to disk, pdflush will be called on a set number, and then pdflush will be scheduled in the next second. I think if subsequent to the first chunk sent to be pdflushed, another page is dirtied, then another chunk will immediately be scheduled before the 1-second timer.

Caveat #2: it still won't be completely synchronous, because pdflush sends its data to the block-level IO scheduler which pushes the write operation into a "queue". But I'm not sure this is any different than what you get with sync-mode.

PS: Don't forget to look at and upvote [this beautiful answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76970/how-do-pdflush-kjournald-swapd-etc-interoperate).